# ffmpeg: overlay a png image on a video with custom transparency?

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, transparency, alpha

Suppose I have a video `foo.mkv` and an image `bar.png` (which happens to contains an alpha channel). I can blend this image over the video like this:

```
ffmpeg 
 -i foo.mkv 
 -i bar.png 
 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay" 
 -vcodec libx264 
 myresult.mkv
```

(using multiple lines here for readability, normally this is one command line).

Now, besides the png image having an alpha channel of its own, I would also apply a custom *overall transparency* when blending this image over the video.

In the above example, the image would be visible 100% on top of the video — or at least the parts where its alpha channel is fully opaque.

Is there a way to add a custom overall opacity or transparency blend factor, something like `opacity=0.5` or whatever, which would make the image only 50% visible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option besides `geq` is `colorchannelmixer`.

```
[1:v]format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[zork]
```

Comment: Thanks! What I like about that is it doesn't force me to explicitly set one of the color channels as well (as is the case with `geq`, hence my dummy `r='r(X,Y)'`). Do you know of a way to force the format to contain alpha, without explicitly forcing the color model as well? (as I am doing with `format=argb`) i.e. is there something like `format=a<currentcolormodel>` ?

Comment: Not in a way that won't overwrite the alpha channel if it does exist.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be a way that would overwrite an existing alpha channel?

Comment: `color=gray,format=gray[c];[c][0]scale2ref[a][v];[v][a]alphamerge[ovrly]` Color gray would ultimately lead to a 50% alpha channel. More tedious, but avoids knowing the source format.

Comment: Another way to get your result is to use the blend filter in overlay mode with opacity of 0.5 applied to top layer.

Comment: Right, I didn't know that one either. Very helpful, I learned a lot, thx!

Comment: @Gyan can you please answer the similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1342355/alphamerge-filter-only-works-on-first-frame)?

Answer (score 20):

I think I got it:

```
ffmpeg 
 -i foo.mkv 
 -i bar.png 
 -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; 
   [0:v][zork]overlay" 
 -vcodec libx264 
 myresult.mkv
```

Where `0.5` is the opacity factor. I'm including `format=argb` so it also works with overlay images that don't have an alpha channel of themselves.

Comment: More complete demonstrative answer

Answer (score -1):

use this function For overlay image with transparency in video in FFmpeg Android

```
fun addimagemerge(inputVideo: String, imageInput: String, output: String): Array<String> {
    val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    inputs.apply {
        add("-i")
        add(inputVideo)
        add("-i")
        add(imageInput)
        add("-filter_complex")
        add("[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[zork]; [0:v][zork]overlay")
        add("-preset")
        add("ultrafast")
        add(output)
    }
    return inputs.toArray(arrayOfNulls<String>(inputs.size))
}
```

Use this for call Function on Convert Button

```
val outputPath = getFilePath(this, VIDEO)
  
    val query = ffmpegQueryExtension.addimagemerge(
        selectedVideoPath!!,
        selectedImagePath!!,
        outputPath
    )

    CallBackOfQuery().callQuery(this, query, object : FFmpegCallBack {
        override fun process(logMessage: LogMessage) {

            runOnUiThread {
                tvOutputPath.text = logMessage.text
            }
        }

        override fun success() {
            tvOutputPath.text = String.format(getString(R.string.output_path), outputPath)
            processStop()
            runOnUiThread {
                videoPlayclass.stopVideoPlay(bottmLay, videoPlayAct)
                videoPlayclass.videoPlayStart(
                    this@MergeImageVideoActivity,
                    bottmLay,
                    videoPlayAct,
                    outputPath
                )
            }
        }

        override fun cancel() {
            processStop()
        }

        override fun failed() {
            processStop()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the significantly simpler top-voted answer? Are there capabilities offered by this approach not available using the command-line options?